# Limit of reserved id name for css in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I created a div with an id of "descriptions" and it fails to recognize the position declaration. Is this a bug in Firefox, or am I missing something here. I am using the latest version of Ubuntu.

**CSS**

```
#descriptions
{
    position: absolute:
    top: 20px;
    left: 190px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100px;   
    background-color: blue; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="descriptions"></div>
```

Here is an active copy: http://jason-rubenstein.com/testCss/test.html

I realize it will work in some browsers, but please verify that this is not a coding issue but a bug.

It does work when I change the name but keep the code the same.

Comment: Your style sheet has a typo: `position: absolute:` (colon instead of a semi-colon) [validators are your friend](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjason-rubenstein.com%2FtestCss%2Ftest.css&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a colon instead of semicolon at the end of the line for the attribute `position: absolute;`

This is the right css code:

```
#descriptions
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 190px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100px;   
    background-color: blue; 
}
```

Comment: I thought that was just a typo when I posted it, let me make sure that' the issue

Comment: I'm embarrassed, I apologize for that. I will accept as soon as it lets me

Comment: Thanks :-) I should be more careful